# Why can't bash recognize the existence of a socket file

Tags: linux, bash, file, sockets

On a Linux box I want to check if a specific socket file exists. I know the socket files exists, but my checks in bash don't show that to me:

```
$ ls -l /var/run/supervisor.sock
srwxrw-rw- 1 root root 0 Jun  3 13:30 /var/run/supervisor.sock  # <== THE FILE EXISTS!!
$ if [ ! -f /var/run/supervisor.sock ]; then echo 'file does not exist!'; fi
file does not exist!
```

Why oh why can't bash see that the file exists?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/fto.html

Use `-S` to test if its a socket. `-f` is for regular files.

See `man 1 test`:

```
   -e FILE
          FILE exists
   -f FILE
          FILE exists and is a regular file
   ...
   ...
   -S FILE
          FILE exists and is a socket
```

Comment: Dang.  You beat me to it.  Same link and everything.  That said, lots of things in Unix are "files".  However, if there's a separate test for that specific kind of file, you should use that instead.

Comment: @Mr.Llama :) This is true. However, -f is specifically for regular files, and so in certain cases cannot be used, such as here.